# Non convex objective in SVM

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, machine-learning

[image]

In the formulation of svm.. The line underline says the norm of the vector w is a non convex constraint.. But how is this so.. Isn't norm a convex function.. Also aren't the other objectives affine.. Hence making the problem feasible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The norm itself is a convex function, but the constraint $\Vert w \Vert = 1$ is not a convex set, and so the problem becomes non-convex. In 2D this would be the unit circle, which is clearly not convex because if you join any two points on the circle by a line you get points not on the circle.